# Call php script on button click and act managing the response

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

I created Php script, which authenticate user when loaded.

It's structure little complex for me but I had to use it. 
I am using this : https://github.com/karimkhanp/twitteroauth reference

Now I have my own login page where I have login via facebook too. And I want to keep button to allow alternate login with twitter.

What I want is: When user click on `Twitter login` button, it should authenticate the user. If authenticate successfully, then redirect to new page let's say 'next.php' also show error message.

Issue: I dont know how to execute php script here on button click, and from php script I need to post `ID` variable to next page start.php where I want to redirect after script complets ..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ThenWat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="Button" id="login1" value = "login | Twitter" onclick="authTwitter();"/>       
        <input type="Button" id="login2" value = "login | Facebook" onclick="authTwitter();"/>      

        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function authTwitter()
            {
                    $.ajax({

                            url: "index.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function(data) {

                            }
                        });                 
            }
            //Please ignore facebook login. it works fine
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.php - which performs twitter login

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
    require_once('config.php');

    if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
        header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
    }
    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
    $twitteruser = $content->{'screen_name'};
    $notweets = 5;
    $tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'mysql');
    echo "<b>Latest 5 tweets:</b> <br/>";
    foreach ($tweets as $item)
    {
        echo $item->text;
        echo "<br/>";
        $tweet = $item->text;
        $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO user_tweets (`id`,`name`,`tweet`,`date`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."','".$tweet."','".$date."')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery1))

        {

            //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

        }
    }

include('html.inc'); 

?>
```

Comment: Your buttons have the same ID, you should use unique Ids

        <input type="Button" id="loginTwitter" value = "login | Twitter" onclick="authTwitter();"/>        
        <input type="Button" id="loginFacebook" value = "login | Facebook" onclick="authTwitter();"/>

Comment: Where is it exactly that you have a problem / an error ?

Comment: @mef: thanks for the help. same button id was just typo. But issue is not regarding that. Problem with me is how to manage script execution from html button click event. When user click on `Login twitter`, it executes 'index.php' script. In this script I get `id` variable if user successfully authenticates. After authencation completes, I want to post `id` variable to `start.php` and redict to that file ..